# MVC, Compile Error with Compiled App_Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some classes in App_Code that are not accessible unless I change them from Content to Compiled. Once I change them to Compiled, I start getting error messages and warnings that aren't making any sense to me.

1:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Warning CS0436  The type 'Article' in 'C:\Users\Ken\OneDrive\Web site\Choatech\App_Code\Article.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Article' in 'choatech, Version=2015.7.5693.41559, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in 'C:\Users\Ken\OneDrive\Web site\Choatech\App_Code\Article.cs'. Choatech    C:\Users\Ken\OneDrive\Web site\Choatech\App_Code\SQLProvider.cs 12

2:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0433  The type 'SQLProvider' exists in both 'choatech, Version=2015.7.5693.41559, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and '1_App_Code, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'   Choatech    C:\Users\Ken\OneDrive\Web site\Choatech\Views\Article\Index.cshtml  24

I understand it's trying to tell me that the item exists twice, but it's referencing the same file both times in the first error... Which isn't making sense to me.

In the second error it's listing some error that appears to be in the project file itself...

Changing the classes to Content resolves the errors, but then my code isn't accessible throughout my application.

I am using MVC, if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try deleting bin and obj folders?

Comment: Yes, and I cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

Comment: Well a quick google search on the Warning Id's you have posted prompted me to suggest you to remove and add your project references again. And are you sure you have not defined the class Article in both Article.cs and SQLProvider.cs?

Comment: Look here second answer is particularly interesting. What usually do in these kind of situations is to delete the entire obj and bin folders and run again. Because most of the times when you clean and rebuild using VS it might leave some content behind in those folders. http://solvedstack.com/questions/where-does-error-cs0433-type-x-already-exists-in-both-a-dll-and-b-dll-come-from

Comment: Hi. I don't have the Article class defined in both. I'm not sure what project references I should be removing. I don't have any project references to these classes. They are just in the App_Code directory.

Comment: I followed that article. I've deleted the bin and obj several times, and restarted IIS and the computer. I cleaned the solution and did a rebuild several times. I will update my post with the code. Maybe you can see something I can't...

Comment: Nevermind, I can't submit the code. The Web site keeps telling me my code isn't intended by 4 spaces when it is, and it refuses to allow me to post.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put these files in App_Code. Source code kept in the App_Code folder is automatically compiled at runtime, resulting in the CS0436 warnings that you are seeing.